# Make a call to a instance of an object from an assembly which references another assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I have a C# .NET 6 project that compiles two assemblies 'in process', one of which references the other. When I create an instance of the object that references the other and\or try to make a method call I receive the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'mydll.dll, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified

How do I persuade the framework to see the referenced library?

```cs
var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assemblyData); // this is a byte array

foreach (var library in buildState.AllReferences)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(library.CompiledData); // this is a byte array.
}

var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(); // confirms that both assemblies have been loaded.

// Error is thrown on this line.
var runner = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateInstance($"{@namespace}.dll", $"{@namespace}.{className}").Unwrap() as ITemplateRunner;

if (runner == null)
    throw new Exception($"{className} is not a ITemplateRunner");

await runner.Execute();
```

I've also tried this, which errors in a difference place...

```cs
var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyData);

foreach (var library in buildState.AllReferences)
{
    var t = Assembly.Load(library.CompiledData);
}

var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

var runner = Activator.CreateInstance(assembly.GetType($"{@namespace}.{className}") ?? throw new Exception("${@namespace}.{className} not in compiled dll.")) as ITemplateRunner;

if (runner == null)
    throw new Exception($"{className} is not a ITemplateRunner");

// now errors here.
await runner.Execute();
```

If there is no reference to the second assembly, the application works as expected.

Both assemblies are in the list returned by `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`, as can be seen in this picture:

[image]

*Edit1:*

Calling `assmbley.CreateInstance()` has the same error message for both variants.

[image]

Comment: `Assembly.Load()` returns an `Assembly` instance. You should be able to call `CreateInstance()` on that.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I'm afraid that results int he same error. Question edited to reflect.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Under the hood `Assembly.CreateInstance` is just a call to `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I write the `byte[]` to a file and then read it in using `Assembly.LoadFrom(filename);` it works. Although it does bring up a problem of the file being locked for writing...

`Assembly.LoadFile()` *doesn't* work.

I have no idea why, but this does at least fix this problem.